# Alternate word for closure

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm developing a UI where college students can post their requests regarding some tips about clearing a game or an overdue assignment etc. Now, these requests are handled by their peers and can be **filled** by someone else.

Recently, some trolls tried to spam the database and I assigned users with special privileges to mark the requests as *closed* in case they are useless or a repetition of older one. But the word **closed** (or *closure*) is misleading as the newer students (AKA users) can think of it being the same as *filling* of the request.

I've written a detailed guide on the difference between closing and filling of a request but I was wondering if **there might be some better word for the same?**

P.S.: I'd prefer if the suggestion is a single word but a small phrase would work too as long as it will not leave any confusion for a new user.

---

### EDIT

Following [StoneyB's comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9982/alternate-word-for-closure#comment16357_9982), I'm now using **blocked** instead of **closed**, but I'm a little sceptic. I still think that blocked is not the correct word to be used with respect to a request. I think something like **voided** or **nullified** would be more appropriate.

Comment: *Blocked* and *canceled* spring to mind, or *suspended* if there is any possibility the request may be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the stackexchange template.

For repetition, you can use *duplicate*.

For useless, you can use *on hold* and can advise the O.P. to reframe the request. Or maybe you can directly use *off-topic*.